# SQL design for notification of new registered users

Tags: sql, database-design, mysqli

I'm with a great difficulty in formulate a SQL for a module of notifications when a new user register.

I have a database of **Notifications**, I set up a notification to be sent. Examples:

- Send notification when a man and blue eyes register;
- Send notification when a woman register;
- Send a notification when a blue-eyed woman, brown and work in the company Foo;

With these rules we can see that there can be several possibilities (so the table columns are optional).

**Some details:**

- The table columns are defined as integers because are FK. I just did not put tables because the structure is unnecessary, since the SQL will only relashionship between User and Notification;
- The date field is used to store both the date of registration of the notice of such person. So I can only filter to notify the new register of user;

---

### Table Structure

```
 User:
 +------------+----------+------+-----+---------+------------+
 | Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra      |
 +------------+----------+------+-----+---------+------------+
 | Id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI |         | auto_incre |
 | Gender     | int(11)  | YES  |     |         |            |
 | HairColor  | int(11)  | YES  |     |         |            |
 | EyeColor   | int(11)  | YES  |     |         |            |
 | Company    | int(11)  | YES  |     |         |            |
 | Date       | datetime | NO   |     |         |            |
 | ...        |          |      |     |         |            |
 +------------+----------+------+-----+---------+------------+

  Notification:
 +------------+----------+------+-----+---------+------------+
 | Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra      |
 +------------+----------+------+-----+---------+------------+
 | Id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI |         | auto_incre |
 | Gender     | int(11)  | YES  |     |         |            |
 | HairColor  | int(11)  | YES  |     |         |            |
 | EyeColor   | int(11)  | YES  |     |         |            |
 | Company    | int(11)  | YES  |     |         |            |
 | Date       | datetime | NO   |     |         |            |
 +------------+----------+------+-----+---------+------------+
```

---

### Initial idea

The initial idea I had was doing a select for each possibility and joining via union:

```
-- Selects new users by gender notification
SELECT * 
FROM Notification
inner join User on (
    User.Date >= Notification.Date and
    Notification.Gender = User.Gender and
    Notification.HairColor is null and
    Notification.EyeColor is null and
    Notification.Company is null
)

union all

-- Selects new users by gender and hair color notification
SELECT * 
FROM Notification
inner join User on (
    User.Date >= Notification.Date and
    Notification.Gender = User.Gender and
    Notification.HairColor = User.HairColor and
    Notification.EyeColor is null and
    Notification.Company is null
)

-- ... and so on, doing a select for each option, resulting in 16 selects (4 columns: gender, hair color, eye color and company)
```

---

## My question is:

Is there another way I can do this SQL querying all the possibilities of notifications in a more easy?
Following this structure of 4 columns we already have 16 selects. In my real structure will have more columns with something unfeasible to keep it that way.
Is there any other suggestion storage structure of the data for a better way to do this functionality?

Comment: have you considered http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_event_processing

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan The page talks about the paradigm, unfortunately not much help in solving my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Notification
inner join User on (
    User.Date >= Notification.Date and
    (Notification.Gender is null or Notification.Gender = User.Gender) and
    (Notification.HairColor is null or Notification.HairColor = User.HairColor) and
    (Notification.EyeColor is null Notification.EyeColor = User.EyeColor) and
    (Notification.Company is null or Notification.Company = User.Company)
)
```

This way you get every set of user with the notification stored in the tables.

Comment: By testing cases that did, seemed to work.  
Seeing that his answer'm feeling a retard!  
A simple solution, at times we are so narrow-minded in developing an application that we do not see simple questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would implement this user registration / notification functionality:

1. Three tables: Users, Notif_type, Notif_queue.
2. A trigger on insert on table Users which calls a stored procedure SendNotification(user_id).
3. The stored proc will have the logic which you can change overtime without having to modify the schema/data. The logic will be:

   - to select the type of notification (form Notif_type) the new user should receive based on your rules;
   - to insert a row in Notif_queue which holds a FK to user_id and notif_type_id, so that the functionality notifying the user is completely de-coupled from the notification rules.

Answer (score 0):

why can't you just use the one table "user" and put an extra field/flag called [Notified] so that every time you want to send notifications just refer it to the flag.

i find it irrelevant to use the notification table.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the functionality I'm doing. Notifications are configured by the system and is customizable according to the entries made ​​in the **Notification** table.